# Admob Ads: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView failed to instantiate

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, ads, adview

Google Play Services Location: 
C:\Users\User\Documents\Eclipse\MyApp\libs & i also added reference to the project ( Green Check ).

Added meta tags correct , declared activity and set permissions ( all double checked )
according to google's tutorial: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

also added the important imports and add banner in xml..Also tried to set the banner at 450dpx75dp according to another similar topic on here.

=======================================================================================

java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 57
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.onMeasure(II)V @20: ifnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 033e 0336 042a 03b6 0015 3a05 2ab6 0014
    0000010: 3a06 1905 c600 2519 05b6 000b 1008 9f00
    0000020: 1b2a 1905 1b1c b600 1919 05b6 000a 3e19
    0000030: 05b6 0009 3604 a700 1f19 06c6 001a 2ab6
    0000040: 0016 3a07 1906 1907 b600 133e 1906 1907
    0000050: b600 1236 041d 2ab6 0018 b800 2a3e 1504
    0000060: 2ab6 0017 b800 2a36 042a 1d1b b800 0d15
    0000070: 041c b800 0db6 001a b1

```
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)

at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)

at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:363)

at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:190)

at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)

at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)

at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)

at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:399)

at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:336)

at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)

at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:517)

at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)

at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)

at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1066)

at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:686)

at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)

at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:778)

at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3080)

at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1772)

at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:279)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)

at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)

at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)

at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)

at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)

at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)

at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)

at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)

at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)

at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)

at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: have You declared the keep-public-class declaration in Your proguard-project.txt file?

Comment: No.actually its the first time i hear about proguard file...Do you have any link to help me out? thanks in advance.

Comment: Proguard is to encrypt Your code, so it´s harder for bad developers to see what You have done. It´s like to protect the secret of Your development and is recommended. I don´t know if You have Proguard inside Your Eclipse IDE, but I think it´s integrated automatically. Please check of You have the proguard-project.txt file inside Your project, it must be at the same place where You find the Android-Manifest.xml.

Comment: here is some info about proguard: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: if You have the proguard-project.txt file, let me know, then I will give You some further information...

Comment: Yes,proguard-project.txt is there...but on project.properties its disabled: 

# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

Comment: I have put an "answer" inside....if it not helps, let me know, then I could delete this...

Comment: Can someone check it over teamviewer/skype? i would appriciate it...mail me at iznoo_mod@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a problem with proguard. Like You said in Your comments, it is disabled, but You should try something. This is not really an answer, but I have to show You some code. So if anyone see this, please don´t downvote.

Open the proguard-project.txt file and put these lines into it:

```
      -keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
         public *;
       }

      -keep public class com.google.ads.** {
         public *;
       }
```

I know that this error comes with obfuscating the app in some cases. It´s worth a try....